# Поток ввода в программу СИ?

Tags: c++, linux, c, bash

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  system("/bin/sh");
  return 0;
}
```

Если просто запустить программу откроется bash, если создать файл echo "ls" > test и запустить программу

```
cat test | ./a.out
```

То отработает ls и программа закроется, почему так происходит, а не дальше ожидается ввод команд в bash?

Если вот так то работает:

```
cat test - | ./a.out
```

Помогите разобраться с логикой конвейера?

Comment: Почему так происходит, хочу разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash будет работать пока не закроется поток ввода. `cat test` отправляет в стандартный ввод содержимое файла и закрывает его. А `cat test -` продолжает после файла перенаправлять свой стандартный ввод в стандартный ввод следующего процесса.